# Оформление запроса с переменными

Tags: php, sql

Нужно сделать запрос, в котором в зависимости от условий можно изменить куда и что мы добавляем. Потому ключевое слово в `$type` позволит определить куда.
Но этот код не работает:

```
$fgpost = mysqli_query($db,"
INSERT INTO ".$type." ("$type._full_name, $type._mobile, $type._email, $type._bd) 
VALUES ('$_POST[$type."_name"]', '$_POST[$type."_number"]', '$_POST[$type."_mail"]', '$_POST[$type."_bd"]')
")
```

Ошибка: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in...`

Можно ли вообще так вставлять переменные в $_POST и при этом все это в запросе?

Comment: `$type." ("$type` - потому и ошибка + никогда так не пишите, про sql-инъекции не слышали?

Comment: Обычно я так не пишу, в данном случае совпало очень красиво и я подумал что так будет намного быстрее и удобней. Что за инъекции?

Comment: @BOPOH Я изменил `".$type."` на `$type`, но теперь ошибка  `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Заработал такой вариант:

```
$fgpost = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO $type 
(".$type."_full_name, ".$type."_mobile, ".$type."_email, ".$type."_bd) 
VALUES ('".$_POST[$type.'_name']."',     '".$_POST[$type.'_number']."', '".$_POST[$type.'_mail']."', '".$_POST[$type.'_bd']."')
") 
or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($db));
```

Не правильно оформил код.

Comment: а теперь представьте, что в `$_POST[$type.'_name']` у вас находится `','','',''); drop table users; -- ` - с большой долей вероятности у вас грохнут таблицу users. Никогда так не делайте

Comment: @BOPOH ну тогда есть 2 варианта: 1) проверить скриптом и отказать если в имени есть что-то кроме букв и пробелов(что я и сделаю чуть позже) 2) использовать preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я\s]/","",$st); (нашел в старом сохраненном файлике, но не проверял). Но тогда мне реально интересно: чем это может быть плохо после вышеприведенных примеров и как сделать иначе?

Comment: "как" - читайте [доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). "Чем" - появится у вас в пользователях какой-нибудь француз, у которого есть апостроф в имени и, если будете так запросы оформлять, он легко сможет получить права админа